# Commands add 0 to relevant columns and cells - Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have 2 commands to add 0 to number (8 digits, 9 digits required), and 0 addition to cell phone numbers (9 digits beginning with 5 digits need to be 10 digits):

**1.Add 0 to 8 digits :**

```
Sub Add_Zeros()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each CL In Selection.Cells
        If CL <> "" Then CL.Value = Application.Rept("0", (9 - Len(CL))) & CL
    Next
End Sub
```

**2.Add 0 to 9 digits :**

```
Sub Add_Zeros()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each CL In Selection.Cells
        If CL <> "" Then CL.Value = Application.Rept("0", (10 - Len(CL))) & CL
    Next
End Sub
```

can I upgrade these codes and combine them as follows?:

A.The first condition: If there are only 8 digits you will add 0 at the beginning (Finally there should be 9 digits)

B.The second condition: If there are 9 digits and the first digit on the left is 5 you add 0 at the beginning (Finally there should be 10 digits)

C.Something else how do I return the command back (ie before the change) to cancel? Do you have a way to insert this into another code?

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 0):

not sure I fully understood, but you could do something like this using `if` `else` and `elseif`

```
Function sort_out_phone(strPhoneIN As String) As String

If Len(strPhoneIN) = 8 Then
    sort_out_phone = "0" & strPhoneIN
ElseIf Len(strPhoneIN) = 9 And Left(strPhoneIN, 1) = "5" Then
    sort_out_phone = "0" & strPhoneIN
Else
    sort_out_phone = "What ever you need to do here"
End If

End Function
```

sort_out_phone("12345678")=012345678

sort_out_phone("123456789")=What ever you need to do here

sort_out_phone("523456789")=0523456789

Comment: Thank you so much, you can please write down a complete and neat code that I could not implement what you presented.
Thanks in advance ,

Comment: @JossephA I have, the lines at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Select Case will help you meet your conditions:

```
Sub Add_Zeros()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    For Each CL In Selection.Cells
        Select Case Len(CL)
            Case 8: CL.value = "0" & CL.Value
            Case 9: CL.value = iif(Left(CL.Value,1)=5,"0","") & CL.value
            Case "" 'do nothing
            Case Else
       End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

I have ignored question C for 2 reasons; 1) because it's not clear and 2) each question should only be one specific question.

Comment: It works great, now how do I cancel? That is, going back, changing the cells from text type to number type, to remove the change (the zeros).

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: you cannot undo changes made from vba. please read [ask] to see about limiting a question to **1**. If you have an additional question, please post a new one.